# Multiple HTTP async request

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, asynchronous, callback

I try to fetch data from different HTTP sources but I wasn't able to handle the asynchronous mode even with `async`...

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var https = require("https");
var timer = require("./my_modules/timer/timer.js");
var http = require('http');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var async = require('async');
var request = require('request');

//These are my source from API.
//Output is a Json file
var sources = {
  cnn: 'https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=cnn&sortBy?&apiKey=c6b3fe2e86d54cae8dcb10dc77d5c5fc',
  bbc: 'https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=cnn&sortBy?&apiKey=c6b3fe2e86d54cae8dcb10dc77d5c5fc',
  guardian: 'https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=cnn&sortBy?&apiKey=c6b3fe2e86d54cae8dcb10dc77d5c5fc',
  othersource: "otherurls..."
};

//I want to push the JSON object in this array
var resultArray = [];

//I setup a https GET request
var getJson = function(url) {
  https.get(url, (res) => {
    var body = '';
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
      body += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function() {
      result = JSON.parse(body);

      //push isn't working...
      resultArray.push(result);
    });

  }).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('Got an error', e);
  });
}

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.listen(
  app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log('We are live on port: ', app.get('port'));
    getJson(sources.cnn);
  });


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.status(404).send('Page not found !');
  res.status(503).send('Page not found, error 503');
});

console.log("resultArray:" + resultArray);
//resultArray  = empty...
```

What should I do to push the result into my Array?
I couldn't find a way to set up a working callback function to push results into the Array.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using the `request` package, have you tried something as simple as:

```
request({
    url: sources.cnn,
    json: true
}, function(error, response, body) {
    var articles = body.articles;

    // or by case, depending on what you want
    // resultArray = resultArray.concat(articles);
    resultArray.push({
        cnn: articles
    });

    console.log(resultArray);
});
```

instead of writing your own `getJson` function?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Roby, your request is much clearer !

I have carefully read this **really clear and helpful** article :  https://github.com/maxogden/art-of-node#callbacks

I think I got the logic :

```
//main function
function getJson(url, callback){
  request({
      url: url,
      json: true,
      callback:callback  //added this
      }, function(error, response, body) {

          var articles = body.articles;
          callback(articles);
      });
}

//this callback function will be passed to the main function as the 2nd parameter
//it's possible to access "resultArray" ONLY from this function
var result = function(e){
  resultArray.push(e);
  console.log(resultArray);
  };

//url and callback are passed as parameter
getJson(sources.cnn, result);
```

Thanks for the help